# Mocking virtual readonly properties with moq

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, mocking, moq

I couldn't find a way to do this, though this can be done by hand so why not with moq?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Given this class

```
public abstract class MyAbstraction
{
    public virtual string Foo
    {
        get { return "foo"; }
    }
}
```

you can set up Foo (a read-only property) like this:

```
var stub = new Mock<MyAbstraction>();
stub.SetupGet(x => x.Foo).Returns("bar");
```

`stub.Object.Foo` will now return "bar" instead of "foo".

Comment: excellent answer thank you. another words, it's better to not have getter-only properties because they are a pain in the ass to mock?

Comment: you see i have a bunch of read only properties: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByqKtGmtuLzZNFhwTWhMMGVRZnc/view?usp=drivesdk and i am trying to use their parent class as the system under test, so im not sure how i would setup the moq, since the system under test is not a mocked class, whereas i want to force a value from those getters

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' A get-only property is only syntactic sugar over a method, so if you take that statement to its logical conclusion, you'd be saying that it's better not to have methods that return data. I don't agree with that at all.

Comment: great point. could you suggest how i can inject those getters into a concrete (non mocked) class?

Comment: apologies if i am not making much sense, thats part of the problem, i just need a way to express/describe this

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' That sounds like a candidate for a new question here on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105481/discussion-between-l-and-mark-seemann).

Comment: here you are, sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827217/how-to-mock-inject-a-getter-into-a-system-under-test

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure property is virtual to make this work.

Comment: When answering an old question which already has an accepted answer, please try to give an answer which either adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to it. As your current answer is right now it's more a comment than an answer. Apart from stating what needs to be ensured for something to work it's usually much more helpful to also include a specific example on how to do it. See also the [contribution guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference.