# How to mock a private readonly IList<T> property using moq

Tags: c#, moq, nbuilder

I'm trying to mock this list:

```
private readonly IList<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

using this (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454186/mocking-virtual-readonly-properties-with-moq)):

```
IList<MyClass> mockList = Builder<MyClass>.CreateListOfSize(5).Build();
mockObj.SetupGet<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(o => o.myList).Returns(stakeHoldersList);
```

However at runtime I get an InvalidCastException:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to
type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[MyClass]'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you expose a public virtual Property of this private readonly member? Plus, if the item in question is private, it sounds like you're not testing the right component.

Comment: @Tejs you're right, please see the updated -now more accurate- question :)

Comment: Please don't edit a question that completely changes the meaning of it. Edits should be for clarifications, not fundamentally changing the meaning. If you want to ask a different question...ask a different question.

Comment: @Jason ok, I'll revert the changes on this one and ask a new question

Comment: new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199544/how-to-mock-a-readonlycollectiont-property-using-moq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Well, I think it's odd and frankly wrong to mock a private implementation detail. Your tests shouldn't depend on private implementation details.**

But the way that I'd do this if I were you is to add a constructor:

```
public Foo {
    private readonly IList<MyClass> myList;
    public Foo(IList<MyClass> myList) { this.myList = myList; }
}
```

and then use Moq to mock an instance of `IList<MyClass>` and pass that through the constructor.

If you don't like that suggestion, alternatively, make a virtual property:

```
public Foo {
    private readonly IList<MyClass> myList = new MyList();
    public virtual IList<MyClass> MyList { get { return this.myList; } }
}
```

and then use Moq to override that property.

**Still, you're doing it wrong.**

Comment: This is basically everything I was going to say. You should only be testing the publicly visible interface anyways.

Comment: @Tejs you're absolutely right. Please see the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199544/how-to-mock-a-readonlycollectiont-property-using-moq

Answer (score 0):

You have a field, but trying to setup a property get.

Changing myList to property *could* work (not a moq expert here):

```
private readonly IList<MyClass> myListFiled = new List<MyClass>();
private IList<MyClass> myList {
  get 
   {return myListFiled;}
}
```