# How to mock a ReadOnlyCollection<T> property using moq

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to mock this ReadOnlyCollection property:

```
private readonly IList<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
public virtual ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass> MyList
{
   get
   {
       return new ReadOnlyCollectionBuilder<MyClass>(this.myList).ToReadOnlyCollection();
   }
}
```

using this mock (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454186/mocking-virtual-readonly-properties-with-moq)):

```
IList<MyClass> mockList = GetElements();
mockObj.SetupGet<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(o => o.myList).Returns(mockList);
```

However at runtime I get an InvalidCastException:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to
type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[MyClass]'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stakeHoldersList is a ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>?

Comment: @payo No, sorry. I've edited the question with the right var name.

Comment: That property getter looks wrong. You shouldn't be recreating the read-only collection each time it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your code really looks like (otherwise it will not compile):

```
// Arrange
IList<MyClass> stakeHoldersList= GetElements();
mockObj.SetupGet<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(o => o.MyList).Returns(stakeHoldersList);
// Act on SUT which uses mockObj
```

You have property MyList of type `ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>` but you are trying to return `IEnumerable<MyClass>`. Thats why you get that error. So, change:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass> stakeHoldersList = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>(GetElements());
mockObj.SetupGet<ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>>(o => o.MyList).Returns(stakeHoldersList);
```

To avoid such runtime errors, do not specify type of SetupGet method. In this case return value type will inferred from property type and you will get error immediately (code won't compile if return value type does not match property type):

```
mockObj.SetupGet(o => o.MyList).Returns(stakeHoldersList);
```

Comment: FYI: This isn't going to compile... ReadOnlyCollection<int> stakeHoldersList = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>(GetElements());

Comment: @TrevorPilley definitely will. Why you think it will not?

Comment: Because you've declared `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` and assigned it as `ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>`...

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thanks! btw great advice not to specify type of SetupGet method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock the private readonly property `myList`, what you can do is override the public property `MyList` since it is marked virtual. In order to do that, you need to update this code:

```
IList<MyClass> mockList = GetElements();
mockObj.SetupGet<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(o => o.myList).Returns(mockList);
```

to this:

```
var mockList = new ReadOnlyCollection<MyClass>(GetElements());
mockObj.Setup(o => o.MyList).Returns(mockList);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I think this can be a little less code.

```
mockObj.SetupGet(o => o.MyList).Returns(GetElements().AsReadOnly);
```