# how to mock/inject a getter into a system under test?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, moq

Mark provides an elegant answer to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972831/to-mock-an-object-does-it-have-to-be-either-implementing-an-interface-or-marked/1973482#1973482).

My class has a read only property:

```
public class myclass
{
    ...
    public virtual string Devicelocation => Message.Message.Items[0].ToString();
    ...
    public someMethod()
    {
        if(Devicelocation=="YourMom")
        {
            //dostuff
        }
        else
        {
            //dootherstuff
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to execute **someMethod()** with an assumption for what Devicelocation is equivalent to.

**How do I mock or inject a value into Devicelocation?**

Comment: It's not very clear what this DeviceLocation property does, you can just probably inject in in class constructor to some private field and make getter use this private field.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up **Devicelocation**  like this:

```
var stub = new Mock<myclass>();
stub.SetupGet(x => x.Devicelocation).Returns("YourMom");

stub.Object.Devicelocation will now return "YourMom".
```

#### Update:

```
stub.Object.someMethod();
```

Comment: how would i execute a concrete instance of someMethod(), assuming a specific value for devicelocation?

Comment: well when you are running a method on the object, i believe you are testing the moq framework itself and not the actual class that you've implemented and intend to test

Comment: Upvoted for the return value.